# Error en Mysql "LineaDireccion1' in field list is ambiguous "

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo este error, bastante rato intentando arreglarlo ,pero nada.

---

Comment: Por favor provee un  [mcve], de otro modo será muy difícil proveer ayuda al respecto y la pregunta puede quedar cerrada

Comment: Yo me aventuro a intentarlo a ciegas... a ver... ¿no será que estas haciendo algun tipo de union de tablas y en ambas hay el mismo campo `LineaDireccion1`?  Para diferenciar de que campo y que tabla se trata debes poner `tabla.LineaDireccion1` en lugar de solo el nombre de campo.... ¿he acertado?  Venga, dime que si :-)

Comment: @masterguru tiene pinta de ser eso

Comment: @Japv Sí, eso me parece, pero vamos, que es una loteria igualmente este tipo de respuestas a ciegas... mira que les gusta a algunos hacernos la vida imposible en lugar de poner el ejemplo de marras :-)

Comment: @masterguru ;Exacto !Maquina . pero al poner tabla.LineaDirecion1, me salta este error:   Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Clientes.LineaDireccion2' in 'field list'